# Read data from Firebase created by loggedin user - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout

I've seen a lot of examples online on how to write and read data to Firebase. However, I want to know how to write and read data from Firebase only created by logged in User.

How do we bind such data to a user?

Thanks

Comment: Wat have u tried

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I'm not sure how to go about it to be honest. There's no clear way from the documentation.

Comment: There is no "binding".  Just use the users's UID in the path of the data you're reading and writing for that user.  There is actually plenty of documentation an samples that illustrate this.  It's up to you to determine the scheme by which you organize per-user data.

Comment: There's no clear documentation between Flutter and Firebase that's what I meant. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on how your data are oranized. Read through this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data

A simple example:

```
// snippet for pulling from data once it is there
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("USERDATA")
  .doc(userID)
  .collection('DOCUMENTS')
  .get()

// one way you might supply the function that puts data up to firestore.
uploadToCloudStorage(
      userID: user.fAuthUser.uid, fileToUpload: File(filePath));
```

Comment: So when I want to retrieve data on userData as in your example, do I need to specify source in getDocuments() ? How do I getDocuments that belong to currentUser()?

Comment: Hi Scott. So I'm trying to retrieve data now, and I can't see the collection('userData').doc()....
The .doc() doesn't show. What I get is .getDocuments() and thereafter, I can't use the orderBy. Can you help with this? thanks.

Comment: hi @hermie_brown. in my example, "USERDATA" is a collection I created beforehand, with that name. In the other answer, they used a sample name of 'user'. You can pick anything you want with that. In this example I have a collection I called USERDATA. In that collection one document is called <value of userID>. Within that document there is a collection I called DOCUMENTS, and in this statement I'm retrieving all of them.. Try hardcoding a fake userID and filling out the firestore data first.
It might be easiest to work on the Upload part before working on the retrieval part

Comment: the existence of .doc, getDocuments, document, set vs. setData and the like, from your comments here and the answer below, depend on which version you're using.

Comment: My Firestore version is 0.13.7.

I asked a new question here. Perhaps it clearly better explains the challenge I'm facing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171621/retrieving-documents-data-into-a-list-where-documentid-is-the-same-as-currentuse

Answer (score 1):

Use the userId to as the docId for the documents in firebase. Here is an example.

```
createOrUpdateUserData(Map<String, dynamic> userDataMap) async {
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
DocumentReference ref =
    Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(user.uid);
return ref.setData(userDataMap, merge: true);}
```

Comment: So when I want to retrieve data on user as in your example, do I need to specify source in getDocuments() ? How do I getDocuments that belong to currentUser()?

Comment: All you need is a datamap .  When you call the function you will just pass a datamap .

Comment: When you retrieve the data you can get the documents whose Id is the same as the user id. That way a user will get his or her record